# What is your favourite plugin in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I find the following things extremely useful in my daily work:

- ido
- emacs muse
- Cscope
- desktop
- tabbar

Comment: survey - consider making community editable, please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've become a huge fan of **org-mode** and muse-mode. I use muse-mode, which I discovered before discovering org-mode to manage a local wiki where I keep mostly work-related notes.

I use org-mode to manage my tasks and use it to take notes. As a task manager I've found it unbeatable.  I intend to migrate my muse-mode notes to org-mode "any day now" ... well, as soon as I get around to hacking up a python script to convert the links for me.  I'll miss some of the more wiki-like features of muse mode, but I think in the end I'll profit from having everything in org-mode.

For me, it replaces OmniOutliner and OmniFocus. Plain text. Works on any platform that supports emacs. Easy kept synchronized between computers using source control. What's not to like?

Comment: I was using planner mode on top of muse mode for the longest of time, and I too am facing the prospect of converting all my planner-mode project pages to org-mode pages.

Comment: I have tried using Emacs for exactly this a couple of times, but each time it has failed and I'm back to paper again. Recently I've been using Tomboy and it is the first time been able to cut down on the ridiculous amount of physical paper I use :)

Answer (score 6):

- anything - its an easy to extend quicksilver for emacs. Nuff said.
- Cedet
- nxml + nxhtml
- ecb
- yasnippets
- Org  (jsut started, already awesmoe)
- All the little libraries I wrote and modified

  - [ToDoChiKu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToDoChiKu) Snarl/growl notification bindings for emacs
  - [FreeTagging](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Tagging) - Provides views into your source code by delicious/flickr style tags.  You can filter a piece of source by a tag (or its negation), and it also displays a tag cloud.
  - [twit.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TwIt) Twitter for emacs
  - [FileJournal](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/file-journal.el) List of most recently used files, with hooks into anything

Comment: What is Free Tagging good for?

Comment: Sorry, shoulda added that.  Answered above.

Answer (score 2):

- [Cedet](http://cedet.sf.net)
- gnus
- w3m
- [emacs-jabber](http://emacs-jabber.sf.net)
- VC & DVC
- AUCTeX
- nxml

Answer (score 1):

[JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/).  It's a great Java developer addition to Emacs.  It adds a lot of the features of the full IDEs (code completion being my favorite).

Answer (score 0):

As a Drupal/PHP developer:

- emacs-starter-kit
- **org-mode**
- magit
- nxhtml
- geben
- ECB

And pianobar for good measure