# Emacs and C++

Tags: c++, emacs

Once again it is time to clean up my emacs setup. Before I go cleaning it up, are there any packages that you would recommend above and beyond c++-mode, cedet, ecb, speedbar etc. ? Especially stuff that's new in the last five years.

Answer (score 2):

[This could be helpful!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271924/what-is-your-favourite-plugin-in-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

I use msf-abbrevs package for inserting code snippets as i type special code words - something like for, if, etc, but with highliting of positions, that should be filled out, and moving between them with TAB key

Answer (score 0):

You might like some of the stuff I added for C programming including splint, cdecl, scons support in making projects  and xcscope.

http://richardriley.net/default/projects/emacs/dotprogramming